Adding princiapl from outside domain to GCP project -- no longer possible?
So it looks like as of May 3, 2024 GCP by default restricts identities and sharing by domain. This means that while it used to be possible to add an outside user to your Firebase app as an editor, or to your IAM. Let's say my GCP org is attached to mydomain.com and I want to add an outside developer at example@example.com even if though example.com is not within my google workspace. This appears to no longer be possible.
While this makes a ton of sense from a security perspective, it's a bit tricky because it seems to require that you pay for another user in Google Workspace. I will say that I have long advised against adding somedeveloper@gmail.com via IAM, and instead creating a new workspace user. But this doesn't work for everybody. For an enterprise I would assume this is no big deal, but for smaller startups this is a bit problematic. This documentation details how to adjust this setting based on conditions, but as far as I can tell you can still only add workspace IDs and/or users that are within your organizational structure in google workspace.
Am I missing something here? Is there a different way to override this and add an outside user if you really need to? I tried all the methods detailed in the above linked documentation, but none of them seem to work if the user is outside of your workspace. Kept saying "cannot be added".
I tried to add an outside user to Firebase app as an editor and I got an error saying my organization policy doesn't allow users from other domains. Followed the docs to override this, but wasn't able to do it for a user in a domain that isn't in my google workspace org structure.
